# why brand-logo is not left aligned with content when full page width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design, materialize

Materialize css version: v0.100.2

Layout behavior requirements:

- responsive side menu that hides when below 992px screen width
- when the side menu is hidden, an icon for the menu appears on the top left
- top navbar is fixed regardless
- When screen width >= 992px, the brand-logo class will center in the navbar
- When screen width < 992px, the brand-logo class will left align

Result: I got it to work according to my requirements

Issue:

When the screen width < 992px, the brand-logo class will left align but **NOT flushed** with the content like the way the menu icon was when screen width >=992px

Note:

This is my first time using codepen and stack snippets. Please correct me if I'm not using them correctly. Am following the examples in https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343424/80353

See my codepen here

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tj_simmons/project/editor/DWQoBY)

See my stackoverflow snippets here

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
});
```

```css
/**
 * Body CSS
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

html,
body,
input,
textarea,
buttons {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.004);
}


/**
 * Layout CSS
 */

 header, main, footer {
   padding-left: 300px;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
   header, main, footer {
     padding-left: 0;
   }
 }


/**
 * helper Classes
 */
.no-margin {
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">




    <body>
      <header>
        <div class="navbar-fixed">
          <nav class="blue" role="navigation">
              <div class="nav-wrapper container">
                <a href="!#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse left no-margin"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <a class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a id="" href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a id="" href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav fixed">
            <li><a id="" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a id="" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </header>
      <main>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="section">
            <br>
            <h1>Brand.io</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sollicitudin volutpat molestie. Nullam id tempor nulla. Aenean sit amet urna et elit pharetra consequat. Aliquam fringilla tortor vitae lectus tempor, tempor bibendum nunc elementum. Etiam ultrices tristique diam, vitae sodales metus bibendum id. Suspendisse blandit ligula eu fringilla pretium. Mauris dictum gravida tortor eu lacinia. Donec purus purus, ornare sit amet consectetur sed, dictum sit amet ex. Vivamus sit amet imperdiet tellus. Quisque ultrices risus a massa laoreet, vitae tempus sem congue. Maecenas nec eros ut lectus vehicula rutrum. Donec consequat tincidunt arcu non faucibus. Duis elementum, ante venenatis lacinia cursus, turpis massa congue magna, sed dapibus felis nibh sed tellus. Nam consectetur non nibh vitae sodales. Pellentesque malesuada dolor nec mi volutpat, eget vehicula eros ultrices.</p>
            <p>Aenean vehicula tortor a tellus porttitor, id elementum est tincidunt. Etiam varius odio tortor. Praesent vel pulvinar sapien. Praesent ac sodales sem. Phasellus id ultrices massa. Sed id erat sit amet magna accumsan vulputate eu at quam. Etiam feugiat semper imperdiet. Sed a sem vitae massa condimentum vestibulum. In vehicula, quam vel aliquet aliquam, enim elit placerat libero, at pretium nisi lorem in ex. Vestibulum lorem augue, semper a efficitur in, dictum vitae libero. Donec velit est, sollicitudin a volutpat quis, iaculis sit amet metus. Nulla at ante nec dolor euismod mattis cursus eu nisl.</p>
            <p>Quisque interdum facilisis consectetur. Nam eu purus purus. Curabitur in ligula quam. Nam euismod ligula eu tellus pellentesque laoreet. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur eu bibendum velit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc efficitur lorem sit amet quam porta pharetra. Cras ultricies pellentesque eros sit amet semper.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>


      <footer class="page-footer blue">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col l6 s12">
              <h5 class="white-text">Footer Content</h5>
              <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">You can use rows and columns here to organize your footer content.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
              <h5 class="white-text">Links</h5>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright">
          <div class="container">
          Made with ♥ by BusinessCoder
          <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>

      

    </body>
```

See screenshot >= 992px. Notice how the logo is NOT flushed with the content
[image]

See screenshot < 992px. Notice the menu icon is flushed with the content

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be some other ways to fix your issue. You faced this issue because your navigation had `position: fixed` and also `width: 100%` in other hand you added `padding-left: 300px` to nav's parent (and other elements) but when you have `fixed` element it wont adjust to its parent and just shift `npx` to the sides.
**Please Note**: This is not the only solution.

**CSS**:

```
nav {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ee6e73;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);/* this will fix your issue */
    height: 56px;
    line-height: 56px;
}
```

Update your `nav` in css or add above code in very last line in your main css file.

**UPDATE:**

This is what works for this exact issue here

Under

```
/**
 * Layout CSS
 */

 header, main, footer {
   padding-left: 300px;
 }

 /**
  * fix the left align for brand-logo
  */
 nav {
   width: calc(100% - 300px);
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
   header, main, footer {
     padding-left: 0;
   }
   /**
    * allows the menu button to be left-aligned in < 992px screen
    */
   nav {
     width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped. but I am going to edit it heavily before I marked it as correct as I cannot use your answer as is else other stuff will break.

Comment: @KimStacks I just tested it in your codepen and didn't broke anything

Comment: The menu button will no longer be left aligned in the < 992px screen. So I had to set nav to width 100% when the screen < 992px wide